# Keep tabindex order if element is hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is a demo fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/gLq2b/

```
<input value="0" />
<input id="test" value="1" />
<input value="2" />
```

If you press TAB repeatedly, it should focus on the 1st, 2nd, then 3rd input by order. So if for some reason, the 2nd input is hidden when it is focused, if you press TAB again, the tabindex order is resetted and you got to start from the beginning.

**How to make it focus on the 3rd input instead when I press TAB again after the 2nd input is hidden?**

Note that the input is just a test case, it could be a radio, a select, or any tabbable element with "tabindex" attribute, etc..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just don't hide it but animate to an opacity of 0 and make the input field as small as possible at the end of the animation

```
$(this).animate({opacity:0}, function(){
    $(this).css({width:0,margin:0,padding:0});   
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gLq2b/5/

Comment: Interesting, I think it's what I'm looking for

Comment: You can also just animate it to a width of 0, it doesn't even look that bad :)

Answer (score 0):

you could change this line `$(this).fadeOut();` to

`$(this).next().focus().end().fadeOut();`

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/gLq2b/2/)

EDIT:
Is this what you're looking for?

```
$(function(){
   $('#test').focus(function(){     
       $(this).fadeOut(function() {
           $(this).next().focus();
       });
   });
});
```

[new example](http://jsfiddle.net/gLq2b/3/)

Comment: Wait it's not how it works. I want it to focus on the 2nd input, wait for it to lost focus then press TAB again to switch to the 3rd. Not switching from 1 to 3rd directly

Comment: It's still not it, I should reach the 3rd input by pressing TAB 2 times, not just one time :(

Comment: @ThanhTrung replace `.next()` with `.prev()` to focus the 1st input so you can hit TAB and move to the 3rd input (but only 1 time, not 2 times). I don't think i have other ideas